# How to convert list elements within a data frame to a data frame

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a data frame with some list items, and within that data frame I would like to convert all the list items to a data frame. The example data frame `df`. I want data frame without any list item.

```
structure(list(Study = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("new", 
"y", "z"), class = "factor"), IQC = structure(list(result.1 = 4, 
    result.2 = 20, result.3 = 2.67), .Names = c("result.1", "result.2", 
"result.3")), EQC = structure(list(result.1 = "1.12*", result.2 = "0.9*", 
    result.3 = 3.1), .Names = c("result.1", "result.2", "result.3"
)), CQCg = structure(list(result.1 = 307.65, result.2 = 307.65, 
    result.3 = 16.16), .Names = c("result.1", "result.2", "result.3"
)), CQCp = structure(list(result.1 = 22.27, result.2 = 20.93, 
    result.3 = 9.59), .Names = c("result.1", "result.2", "result.3"
)), AQCg = structure(list(result.1 = 10.8, result.2 = 8.99, result.3 = 8.37), .Names = c("result.1", 
"result.2", "result.3")), AQCp = structure(list(result.1 = 3.81, 
    result.2 = "1.07*", result.3 = "0.2*"), .Names = c("result.1", 
"result.2", "result.3")), Rank = c(1.42, 1.92, 2.67)), .Names = c("Study", 
"IQC", "EQC", "CQCg", "CQCp", "AQCg", "AQCp", "Rank"), row.names = c(NA, 
3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `unlist` to do what you need. I hope this is helpful.

```
unlisted <- as.data.frame(t(apply(df, 1, unlist)))
```

Answer (score 3):

To remove the `list` class from any column in the data.frame, one could simply use

```
df[] <- unlist(df)
```

After this conversion, the entries displayed in the data.frame remain unchanged:

```
#> df
#  Study  IQC   EQC   CQCg  CQCp AQCg  AQCp Rank
#1     1    4 1.12* 307.65 22.27 10.8  3.81 1.42
#2     3   20  0.9* 307.65 20.93 8.99 1.07* 1.92
#3     2 2.67   3.1  16.16  9.59 8.37  0.2* 2.67
```

But one can verify that the list columns have been converted into character columns:

```
#> sapply(df,class)
#  Study         IQC         EQC        CQCg        CQCp        AQCg        AQCp        Rank 
#"character" "character" "character" "character" "character" "character" "character" "character"
```

PS: Hat tip to @docendodiscimus for pointing out a mistake in a previous version of this answer.

Comment: @docendodiscimus Maybe I have misread the question. I thought the goal was to remove all non-list columns.

Comment: @docendodiscimus I think you're right. I'll try to correct this.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I think only  `unlist(df)` is not the solution. It changes the format of the dataframe.

Comment: @Hashim Please note the empty square brackets on the left hand side of the assignment: `df[] <- unlist(df)`. They are essential for this solution.

Comment: I don't know how to explain, but, the data frame get so wide by your code, and on checking `ncol`, it return `NULL`,

Comment: @Hashim What you describe corresponds to the result of `unlist(df)` and `ncol(unlist(df))`. But this is only half of the solution (the right hand side). Please do not ignore the left hand side, using the same name as the data.frame that you are trying to convert, and including the empty square brackets as described in the answer.